# teamcity xbuild on linux

Tags: linux, mono, teamcity, xbuild

When I run my build it will fail with the following log:

```
[14:14:45]Checking for changes
[14:15:02]Publishing internal artifacts
[14:15:02]Clearing temporary directory: /var/TeamCity/buildAgent/temp/buildTmp
[14:15:02]Free disk space requirement
[14:15:02][Free disk space requirement] Free disk space requirement of 3.0Gb is not met for directory /var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/870524f98b27404c (only 2474.7Mb is free).
[14:15:02][Free disk space requirement] Free disk space requirement of 3.0Gb could not be met for directory /var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/870524f98b27404c (only 2474.7Mb is free)
[14:15:02]Checkout directory: /var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/870524f98b27404c
[14:15:02]Repository sources transferred
[14:15:02]Updating sources: server side checkout
[14:15:02]Starting: /usr/bin/mono /var/TeamCity/buildAgent/plugins/dotnetPlugin/bin/JetBrains.BuildServer.MsBuildBootstrap.exe /workdir:/var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/870524f98b27404c /msbuildPath:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/xbuild.exe
[14:15:02]in directory: /var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/870524f98b27404c
[14:15:03]Process exited with code 1
[14:15:03]MSBuild output
[14:15:03][MSBuild output] Start MSBuild...
[14:15:03][MSBuild output] '/usr/bin/mono' '/usr/lib/mono/4.0/xbuild.exe "@/var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/870524f98b27404c/MyNancy.sln.teamcity.msbuild.tcargs" MyNancy.sln'
[14:15:03][MSBuild output] working dir = '/var/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/870524f98b27404c'
[14:15:03][MSBuild output] MSBUILD: error MSBUILD0004: Too many project files specified
[14:15:04]Publishing internal artifacts
[14:15:04][Publishing internal artifacts] Sending build.finish.properties.gz file
[14:15:04]Build finished
```

Is there a way to catch the tcargs file contents? It is not in the temp dir of the buildagent. Maybe someone knows what I am doing wrong. When I call the xbuild on the working dir manually it builds fine.
Thanx

Comment: Did you try to use xbuild with the extra "/verbosity:diagnostic" switch? Then you should be able to see all the log entries and learn why it breaks.

Comment: That tcargs file probably already specifies a project file to build, and so you get that error.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this question?  I have the same issue now, and it's rather perplexing.

Comment: No, did not. I use Jenkins now and it works like a charm!